# RavenDb facet search in string array field with wildcard

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

Is it possible to have a RavenDb faceted search, in a `string[]` field, where I would want to show facets (counts) for only values starting with a particular string, rather a range?

I'll try to explain myself better to with a simple example, imagine having an index with the below entries

```
ID | Values
-------------------------
1  | CatPersian, CatNormal, DogLabrador
2  | CatPersian, Camel, DogPoodle
3  | CatNormal, CatBengali, DogNormal
4  | DogNormal
```

I would perform a query on the above documents, and the Facet search would  include a range of 'Cat*', on the 'Values' field.  Is this possible?  Then, I would get a result based on just the different values for cats, like:

- CatPersian [2]
- CatNormal [2]
- CatBengali [1]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. Index the array, and then just use facets normally.
Let's see the full example. You have the following documents:

```
{
    "Name": "John",
    "FavoriteAnimals": [
        "Cats",
        "Dogs",
        "Snails"
    ],
    "@metadata": {
        "@collection": "Kids"
    }
}

{
    "Name": "Jane",
    "FavoriteAnimals": [
        "Cats",
        "Rabits"
    ],
    "@metadata": {
        "@collection": "Kids"
    }
}
```

Now, you create the following index:

```
from k in docs.Kids
from animal in k.FavoriteAnimals
select new { Animal = animal }
```

And run this query:

```
from index 'YourIndex'
where startsWith(Animal , 'ca')
select facet('Animal')
```

And the result will be:

```
{
    "Name": "Animal",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Count": 2,
            "Range": "cats"
        }
    ]
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this index:

```
from k in docs.Kids
select new { k.FavoriteAnimals }
```

And run this query:

```
from index 'YourIndex'
where startsWith(FavoriteAnimals , 'ca')
select facet('FavoriteAnimals')
```

The difference here is that you'll get all matches for the documents that have a match.
So in this case

```
{
    "Name": "Animal",
    "Values": [
        {
            "Count": 2,
            "Range": "cats"
        },
        {
            "Count": 1,
            "Range": "dogs"// also, snails, rabbits
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example, or is there documentation related to it?  As far as I know, for facet range search you should provide a 'range' for values to be between, e.g 1 - 5, 6 - 10. However in this case I would need something more similar to a wildcard search, where the facet range would be just 'Cat*'.  I would then need the result of each distinct item matching that wildcard, not as a group telling me the counts for the entire 'Cat*' group.